# Conditional Dash registration output - redirect vs display div depending on success status

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, flask-login

I'm trying to implement a simple registration page in Dash using Flask-login.

The page should:

1. Redirect user to login if registration is successful
2. Stay on the same page and display error message if not

I've gotten it to work with displaying registration 'success' message on the same page (the login box appears undernearth registration form upon successful registration)

This feels clumsy and suboptimal however, but I've had trouble with capturing a 'pathname' Output and a 'children' Output in the callback. I'd also tried returning `url_for` but it does not work because I'm using the dash format rather than the flask routes.

How can I get the registration form to redirect to login page upon successful registration?

```
callbacks.py


app.validation_layout = html.Div([layout_query_move,])

def visualise_output(df):
    return px.scatter(df, x=[0,0], y=[0,0])

#CALLBACK FOR SHOWING CONDITIONAL INPUT BOXES
@app.callback(
    Output('graph0', 'figure'),
    Input('submit-button-state-go-run-query', 'n_clicks'),
    State('EVENT_ID_state', 'value'), #
    State('MASTER_TICKER_STR_state', 'value'),
    State("full-input-boxes", "children"),
             )
def display_value0(n_clicks,event_id,master_ticker_str, children):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [0, 0], 'y': [0, 0]})
    fig = px.scatter(df, x=[0,0], y=[0,0])
    fig_pg_0 = fig
    if children: 
        fig_pg_0 = visualise_output(df)
        #if children == type0 --> process input method 0
        #if children == type1 --> process input method 1
    return fig_pg_0

@app.callback(
    Output('full-input-boxes', 'children'),
    Input('submit-button-choose-event', 'n_clicks'),
    State('EVENT_ID_state', 'value'),
)
def ask_for_more_inputs(n_clicks,event_id):
    if not n_clicks: raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
    if event_id == 'MOVE': return layout_query_move
    return layout_query_fundamental

#LOGIN FORMS
@app.callback(
    Output('url_logout', 'pathname'),
    [Input('back-button', 'n_clicks')])
def logout_dashboard(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks > 0: return '/register'

@app.callback(
    [Output('container-button-basic', "children"),
     #Output('url_loginxx', 'pathname')
     ],
    [Input('submit-val', 'n_clicks')],
    [
        State('email_username', 'value'),
        State('password', 'value'),
    ]
)
def insert_users(n_clicks, email_username, pw):
    hashed_password = ''
    if pw is not None: hashed_password = generate_password_hash(pw, method='sha256')
    if email_username is not None and pw is not None: #is not None:
        ins = users.Users_tbl.insert().values(username=email_username, password=hashed_password)
        conn = users.engine.connect()
        conn.execute(ins)
        conn.close()
        return [html.Div([html.H2('registration successful!'),login])] #redirect(url_for('/'))
    else:
        if email_username is not None:
            if '@' not in email_username:
                return [html.Div([html.H2('error: invalid username')])]
        if pw is not None:
            if len(pw) <6:
                return [html.Div([html.H2('error: password too short')])]
        errors = False
        if errors == False: return [html.Div([html.H2('')])]

@app.callback(
    Output('url_login', 'pathname')
    , [Input('login-button', 'n_clicks')]
    , [State('uname-box', 'value'), State('pwd-box', 'value')])
def successful(n_clicks, input1, input2):
    user = users.Users.query.filter_by(username=input1).first()
    if user:
        if check_password_hash(user.password, input2):
            login_user(user)
            return '/welcome'
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass

@app.callback(
    Output('output-state', 'children')
    , [Input('login-button', 'n_clicks')]
    , [State('uname-box', 'value'), State('pwd-box', 'value')])
def update_output(n_clicks, input1, input2):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        user = users.Users.query.filter_by(username=input1).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, input2):
                return ''
            else:
                return 'Incorrect username or password'
        else:
            return 'Incorrect username or password'
    else:
        return ''

@app.callback(
    Output('url_login_success', 'pathname')
    , [Input('back-button', 'n_clicks')])
def logout_dashboard(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks > 0: return '/register'

@app.callback(
    Output('url_login_df', 'pathname')
    , [Input('back-button', 'n_clicks')])
def logout_dashboard(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks > 0: return '/register'
```

```
layouts.py

#CONSTANTS
list_of_events = []
label_width = '15%'
input_width = '25%'
desc_width = '30%'
br = html.Br()
hr = html.Hr()

#DECLARATION OF NAVBAR
navbar_with_login = dbc.NavbarSimple(
    children=[
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("login/register", href="/login",external_link=True)), #<< LOGIN BUTTON
        #dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("logout", href="/logout",external_link=True)), #<< THE LOGGED OUT VIEW
        dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink("about", href="/about",external_link=True)),
    ],
    brand="placeholder",
    brand_href="/",
    color="dark",
    dark=True,
)

#SOME INTERNAL WORKINGS
b1 = html.Td(dbc.Button('About', outline=True,size='lg',href='/query', color="dark",className="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto"))
d1 = html.Td([html.P('about')])
row1 = html.Tr([b1, d1])
table = dbc.Table([html.Tbody([row1])], bordered=False,borderless=True)

layout_menu = html.Div([table])

optionlist = [{'label': 'Move in price of fixed size and time', 'value': 'MOVE'},]
for el in list_of_events: optionlist.append({'label': el,'value': el}) #print("EL: ", el)

event_selection_label = html.Div([dbc.Label("Event: ", size="md")], style={'width': label_width, 'display': 'inline-block'})
empty_box = html.Div([dbc.Label(" ", size="md")], style={'width': label_width, 'display': 'inline-block'})
event_selection_menu = html.Div(
    [dcc.Dropdown(id='EVENT_ID_state',options=optionlist,value='MOVE')],
        style={"width": "25%",'display': 'inline-block'}
)

ticker_selection_label = html.Div([dbc.Label("Ticker: ", size="md")], style={'width': label_width, 'display': 'inline-block'})
ticker_selection_menu = dcc.Input(id='MASTER_TICKER_STR_state', type='text', value='QQQ', style={"width": input_width},)

layout_query_menu = html.Div([
    html.H3('''select ticker, event, and click to show *all inputs*''', id='h1', style={'text-align': 'center'}),
    event_selection_label,event_selection_menu,
    br,
    ticker_selection_label,
    ticker_selection_menu,br,
    empty_box,dbc.Button(id='submit-button-choose-event', n_clicks=0, children='click to show all inputs',style={'width': input_width,'margin-bottom': '10px'}),  # remove the =0 ?
    html.Div(id='full-input-boxes'),
    empty_box,dbc.Button(id='submit-button-state-go-run-query', n_clicks=0, children='Go!',style={'width': input_width,'margin-bottom': '10px'}),br,hr,
    dcc.Graph(id='graph0',figure={"layout":{"height": 1000}}),
])


layout_about = html.Div([
    html.H3('About',style={'text-align': 'center'}),
    html.P('description',style={'text-align': 'center'}),
])


layout_front_page =  html.Div([
            html.Div(style={'height':'50px'}),
            html.H3('''Welcome''', id='w1',style={'text-align': 'center'}),
            html.Div([html.P('''description''', id='w2'),
            dbc.NavLink('learn more', active=True, href="/about")],
            style={"width": "100%",'text-align':"center",'justify':"center",'align':"center"},),
        ])

#move layout
move_input_and_label_list = []
move = {'start_date':0,'end_date':0}
ll = list(move.keys())
for i in range(3,len(list(move.keys()))):
    key = ll[i]     #print(ll[i])
    val = des.move[key]
    typeval = 'number'
    if key in ['from_date','to_date','option_type']: typeval = 'text'
    labl = html.Div([dbc.Label(key, size="md")], style={'width': label_width, 'display': 'inline-block'})
    inpval = dcc.Input(id=key, type=typeval, value=val, style={"width": "25%"}, )
    move_input_and_label_list.extend([labl,inpval,br])
layout_query_move = html.Div(move_input_and_label_list)

#LOGIN-REGISTER-LOGOUT CALLBACKS
register_row = dbc.Row(
    [
        dbc.Row(dcc.Input(id="email_username", type="email", placeholder='user@email.com', maxLength =32)),
        dbc.Row(dcc.Input(id="password", type="password", placeholder="password")),
        dbc.Row(html.Button('Register', id='submit-val', n_clicks=0)),
        dbc.Row(html.Div(id='container-button-basic'),),
    ],
    className="g-0",
)

layout_register = html.Div([
    html.H3('register',style={'text-align': 'center'}),
    dcc.Location(id='create_user', refresh=True),
    dbc.Container([register_row]),
    dbc.NavLink("registered? login!", active=True, href="/login",style={'text-align': 'center'}),
],
    style={"height": "100%",'justify':"center",'align':"center",'text-align': 'center'},
)


login_row = dbc.Row(
    [
        dbc.Row(dcc.Input(placeholder='username@email.com',type='text',id='uname-box')),
        dbc.Row(dcc.Input(placeholder='password',type='password',id='pwd-box')),
        dbc.Row(html.Button(children='Login',n_clicks=0,type='submit',id='login-button')),
        dbc.Row(html.Div(children='', id='output-state')),
    ],
    className="g-0",
)

login = html.Div([dcc.Location(id='url_login', refresh=True),
    html.H3('''login to continue''', id='h1',style={'text-align': 'center'}),
    dbc.Container([login_row]),
    dbc.NavLink("not registered? register!", active=True, href="/register",style={'text-align': 'center'}),
],
    style={"height": "100%",'justify':"center",'align':"center",'text-align': 'center'},
)

failed = html.Div([dcc.Location(id='url_login_df', refresh=True)
            , html.Div([html.H3('login to continue'),br,
                    html.Div([login]),br,
                    html.Button(id='back-button', children='Go back', n_clicks=0)
                ]) 
        ])

logout = html.Div([dcc.Location(id='logout', refresh=True)
        , html.Br()
        , html.Div(html.H3('you have been logged out'))
        , html.Br()
        , html.Div([login])
        , html.Button(id='back-button', children='Go back', n_clicks=0)
    ])
```

```
init.py

# callback to reload the user object
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return users.Users.query.get(int(user_id))

#MAIN APP LAYOUT - WHICH DISPLAYS NAVBAR
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    navbar_with_login,
    html.Div(id='page-content'),
])
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return users.Users.query.get(int(user_id))

#MAIN APP NAVIGATION SCHEME
@app.callback(
        Output('page-content', 'children'),
        Input('url', 'pathname')
             )
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/':
        return layout_front_page
    if pathname == '/login':
        return login
    elif pathname == '/register':
        return layout_register
    elif pathname == '/welcome':
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            return layout_menu
        else:
            return failed
    elif pathname == '/about': return layout_about
    elif pathname == '/logout':
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            logout_user()
            return logout
        else:
            return logout
    else:
        return '404'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True,port=5000) #,host='0.0.0.0'
```

Comment: Can you provide the full layout and callbacks code? Otherwise we kinda have to guess and make up our own in order to test and try and help troubleshoot; which, is doable, but just takes extra time. I know the SO docs say don't provide the full source code, but with Dash it's kind of an exception. I mean, it's pretty amazing that in a single SO question such complex questions regarding the functionality of entire apps can even be asked. I don't think they envisioned that ten+ years ago

Comment: hey @JohnCollins ! great to hear from you! Absolutely - it is indeed very hard to capture the issue without posting the entire source. I'd added the code from layouts callbacks and init in the post - but I think it would be much easier with a github repo: https://github.com/ya1220/flask_app_with_login_registration/ - I've created a condensed version of the app to illustrate the issue

Comment: Oo this is a tough one, and unfamiliar territory for me with the flask extensions specifics. I happened to just be working with an extremely similar project the other day though: https://github.com/seanmajorpayne/openDashAuth, which you may already have seen as well. It's definitely helpful for working on your particular situation -- I've spent some time looking at yours but I have not quite yet figured it out. If I have time, will def let you know if I manage to be able to get yours to work. Legitimately secure user login for dash apps is sth i've always wanted to look into...

Comment: You may want to consider copying this seanmajorpayne's method/pkgs/flask extensions usage a little more exactly? Because when I was playing around with that the login was successfully working

Comment: @JohnCollins thank you! The link was extremely helpful - through references to it, I found an even more similar one here: https://github.com/russellromney/dash-auth-flow/ . The actual solution ended up being quite straightforward - just declaring the navlink as an element and having a callback to it depending on user authentification status. Thank you again!!

Comment: Awesome!! Totally love that dash-auth-flow repo. MUCH simpler and easier to understand implementation; think I'll take advantage of that myself  nice find / solution

Answer (score 1):

Ended up getting it to work like this - with a Navlink referencing an id and a callback populating that element id

```
header = dbc.Navbar(
    dbc.Container(
        [
            dbc.NavbarBrand("website.com", href="/"),
            dbc.Nav(
                [
                    dbc.NavItem(dbc.NavLink('login', id='user-action', href='Login')),
                ]
            )
        ],
    ),
)


@app.callback(
    [Output('user-action', 'children'),
     Output('user-action', 'href'),
     ],
    [Input('page-content', 'children')])
def user_logout(input1):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return 'logout', '/logout'
    else:
        return 'login', '/login'
```